# Getting bash to prompt the deletion of related dotfiles

Tags: linux, bash, rm

I find that I end up in this situation on Ubuntu often, and I was wondering if there's a neat way to solve it.

Suppose I am writing some C++ programs, say `a.cpp`, `b.cpp` and `c.cpp`. During testing, I generate a lot related files like `a.out`, `.a.out~`, `.a.un~` etc. If at some point later I realise that I no longer need `a.cpp`, I can perform `rm a.cpp`. But then I am left with a clutter of associated junk that is no longer relevant.

I am aware that I can perform periodic `rm .*.un~` but I'm hoping for a better way. Is there a way I can get `rm` to prompt me at the point of deleting `a.cpp` with something like

```
rm: remove regular file 'a.cpp'? y
rm: remove associated file '.a.un~' too?
```

which I can then say 'y' or 'n' to?

Comment: `rm() { command rm -i "$@"; for x; do test -f "$x.un~" && command rm -i "$x.un~"; done; }`

Comment: Ah yes, thanks! I shall play around with a similar script :)

Comment: For this [make](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)) has been invented.

Comment: You can also use `find`, e.g. `find . -type f -name ".pattern*" -execdir rm -i '{}' +`, though it offers little over a function with `rm` itself as @WilliamPursell indicates.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example Makefile.

```
all:
    g++ -o a a.cpp

clean:
    rm -f *~
```

Make sure to keep the tabulators in front of `g++` and `rm`.

Compile with `make all` and clean up with `make clean`.

Comment: Unfortunately, as written, it does not prompt for confirmation before delete as requested in the question -- and using `make` as a wrapper for `rm` is -- creative, but not what you would generally call the proper tool for the job. No downvote, but certainly -- skeptical.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin This is the way development works. It is called build process. And Make is one of the most important [build tools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_build#Build_tools) for C and C++ development. Nobody wants to answer questions during the build process. The most important aspect for the build process is its reproducibility. It is a necessary condition for [continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration). If you want to do it the "right way" use Make or anything better.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I'm not knocking `make`, I use it extensively. My comment pertains to the use of `make` to perform an `rm` operation, *in-and-of-itself*, rather than using `rm` directly to perform `rm`. That is why I did not downvote, you are free to use a Makefile to do what you like, but that still doesn't change the fact that it is somewhat a leap to turn the thought of "*Hey, I need to delete a few files, how?*", into "'*I know, I'll write a Makefile to do it!*"

Comment: This is a nice idea, but I use `make clean` to mean 'delete all object and executable files'. If I rename files, I wouldn't want to run a `make clean` to remove editor generated garbage, for eg, if compilation time is large and I don't want to delete my executables and object files. I understand that I could write a `make veryclean` to do so, but I would like to separate project-related cleanliness with local, my-editor-and-my-system-specific cleanliness, especially because I would usually add Makefiles to my git repository, as they are usually shipped along with source code.

Comment: @GlobeTheatre Often that is called [`distclean`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477788/what-does-make-distclean-do)